# Compare app code on Android test phone to code on the IDE

Tags: android, debugging

I tested an app on my phone then I changed the code and the app stopped working properly. (I tested it on the emulator this time so the test phone has an older version)Can I download the app code from the phone to see what I may have erased erroneously.

The specific issue is that I had a recycler view open when the activity was called but it stopped doing that. I have to navigate away from it and back for it to work.

If I can get the answer to the first part, that's what I need in the long run if this happens again and if you can guide me on the second part, it would be a plus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do that using reverse engineering for you Apk , 
there are many tools to do that and you will got your java code , have a look on this 
[link](https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/)

But my advice to find the Error with your new code not to go back to old one

Comment: I wanted to see if there was a tool for it. I start by going through my code thoroughly but I haven't look at this piece in a while and I would probably not be able to say if something is missing. It's probably the order of the code since the app works. Just not how I need it to

Comment: okay , so you can use Apk tool to get your old code and compare :)